# Error when attempting loaddata on django database dump

Tags: python, django, database

I started a new `Django` project, the database I had before was still relevant so I want to merge it over to the new one using `dumpdata & loaddata.`

I am using the out of the box database django comes with: `sqllite`.

The problem is when I use loaddata I get this error:

```
bad_row[1], referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name,
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixtures: The row in table 'django_admin_log' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: django_admin_log.content_type_id contains a value '7' that does not have a corresponding value in django_content_type.id.
```

The steps I followed to get here are:

1. Copied and migrated the models page from my first project to my new one.
2. `python3 manage.py dumpdata admin > db.json --indent 2`
3. `python3 manage.py loaddata db.json`

tldr; My goal is to take the data from the old database in another project and put it in the new project's database.

Comment: why not use dumpdata/loaddata on a specific app? `python manage.py dumpdata myapp > myapp.json` then `python manage.py loaddata myapp.json`

Comment: When I try I get the error 'No installed app with the label 'Myappname''

Comment: You need to use natural primary key serialisation when you dump the content_types data, and natural foreign keys when you dump the data that references it. But I'm not sure you really need the admin_log data anyway, do you?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I only did that because it was the only way I could get it to migrate over without the models being registered under the old app in the json.

Comment: @AshishAcharya when I do that I get a 'Invalid model identifier' error come time to loaddata

Comment: As I say, see the [--natural-primary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-dumpdata-natural-primary) and [--natural-foreign](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-dumpdata-natural-foreign) options for dumpdata.

Comment: Will do thank you for your feedback